# Let a method modify the reference instead of a new object

Tags: java, object, methods, reference

i bet this question has been already answered, but i dont know how to explain the question in simple words to find a simple answere on google - I'm sorry!

This is my test-code:

```
public class test {
public static void increase(Integer i){
    i++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer x = new Integer(10);
    increase(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

I have an Integer x and want to modify it through a void-method "increase(..)".
Since Integer is an Object, x is a pointer to that object.
I want "increase(..)" to modify the Integer itself, so "i" refers to the same object as "x" does. But if i look at the print(x) (which is "10") i assume that the method creates a new Integer with the content of "x".

I hope one can understand me...

What i need that for?

I am trying to use multiple threads to sum up the numbers from 1 to "n". 
I created a Class "MyThread" which gets a lowerLimit and an upperLimit to sum up the interval, and a "result" (but as reference - not a new object) where the numbers of the intervals are added onto.

Best Regards
Tak3r07

Answer (score 3):

There is three ways to do this.

```
public class test {
public static void increase(AtomicInteger i){
    i.getAndIncrement()
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(10);
    increase(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

or

```
public class test {
public static void increase(int[] i){
    i[0]++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] x = { 10 };
    increase(x);
    System.out.println(x[0]);
}
}
```

or with Integer

```
public class test {
public static void increase(Integer[] i){
    i[0]++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer[] x = { 10 };
    increase(x);
    System.out.println(x[0]);
}
}
```

> Out of interest, can you explain why this works? I thought java was strictly pass by value?

Java is pass by value.  The reference is passed by value, however this is a shallow rather than a deep copy.  i.e. you can't change the reference, but you can change the object referenced.

You can't do this directly with `Integer` as it is immutable, so there is nothing you can change.  Pass a reference to a mutable object and you can change that.

Comment: +1 Peter. Out of interest, can you explain why this works? I thought java was strictly pass by value? (so that when you pass an object to a method, that method works with a copy of the object). So confused now as to why Integer doesnt work but an int[] does

Answer (score 2):

The `Integer` class like the `String` and the other primitive wrapper classes are immutable ,this means that their value cant be changed,so every time you are trying to change their value you are actually creating a new instance of them.You can use the `AtomicInteger`,`AtomicLong`,`AtomicDouble`... for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think i already heard of them being immutable but forgot it. I assume derivates of immutable classes are immutable aswell?

Comment: @Tak3r07 , Immutables are final ,this means you cant make a class that extends them.

Answer (score 2):

An expression of the form `e++` is shorthand for

```
E old = e;
e = (E) (old + 1);
return old;
```

where `E` is the type of `e`.

That is, your expression is equivalent to

```
i = (Integer) (i + 1);
```

Which is evaluated by computing i + 1, creating (or reusing) an Integer object to hold that value, and storing the reference to that object in the variable i. The original Integer object is not modified, and the caller still references that original object, and therefore sees the original value.

To fix this, you can either return a reference to the new Integer object, and require the caller to store it, or pass a reference to an object of a class that supports changing the value. Alas, Integer is no such class as its value can not be changed once the object has been created. See Peter's and Braj's answers for examples of suitable classes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class that does what you want:

sample code:

```
public class MyInteger {
    int value;

    public MyInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void increase() {
        value++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

}

....

public static void main(String[] args){

    MyInteger x = new MyInteger(10);
    x.increase();
    System.out.println(x.getValue());  // print 11
    System.out.println(x);             // print 11

}
```